# How to nest if (isset($_POST['submit'])) (with tokens also)

Tags: php, submit, form-submit, isset

I have that code and it work fine:

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
    {
        if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
            unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
            include_once('./token.php');
            include_once('./my2page.php'); //**PAGE WITH SUBMIT2**
        } else {
          header("location: ./index.php");
        }
    } else {
        include_once('./token.php');
        include_once('./my1page.php'); //**PAGE WITH SUBMIT1**
    }
```

token.php

```
$form_token = uniqid();
$_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
```

The form in my1page.php contains:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>">
```

Now i need to nest a second if isset submit (token must be unset in the last submit).

**WHAT I TRIED WITHOUT SUCCESS**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['submit']=true;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit'])) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
           if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
                unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit']=false;
                include_once('./script/token.php');
                include_once('./my3page.php');
           } else {
            header("location: ./3.php");
           }
       }
       include_once('./my2page.php');
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./my1page.php');
}
```

Comment: in your unsuccessful try you have  a redundant if `if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {`  as you already check it above.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP works stateless. That means that what is happening here is the following:

1. User calls this page for the first time. He sends a GET request so `isset($_POST['submit1'])` is false.
2. Now he clicks on submit and sends the first POST request. (I assume that you set a value for submit1 there.) `isset($_POST['submit1'])` is true and `my2page.php` gets returned.
3. He sends the third request. Again a POST request, but this time with a value for submit2. Your server template engine starts evaluating the php. `isset($_POST['submit1'])` is false, so it returns the old `my1page.php`

---

Basically, don't nest your checks, but use a `it else` instead. (Think of it as a switch/case

```
isset($_POST['submit1']) → ./my2page.php
isset($_POST['submit2']) → //end page
none                     → ./my1page.php
```

Comment: You are right! But what do you mean with: Basically, don't nest your checks, but use a it else instead. etc....? I have a page with search form (my1page) that return a table with result (my2page)...after i need submit some query to result (mySUBMIT2)!

Comment: Well instead of checking for request 1 and if it is true also check for request 2, check for the second option if the first one is not the case. (`if(request1) SendPage1 else if (request2) SendPage2 else SendIndex`)

Comment: but the pages are 1 next to each other

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I search the word in my1page, after i press submit1 and i can see results in a table. After i select checkboxes in the table and i press submit2 and my3page process my selection and returns results to me

Comment: That sounds like you do not want this at all, but should rather be working with Ajax-Calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 submits in the same time so what happens here is

```
if(condition){
   if(!condition){
      //do somthing
   }
}
```

this will never works try to use another page or i advice to save the first submit in the $_SESSION;

ADD this lign

```
$_SESSION['submit1'] = (isset($_POST['submit1']))? true: false;
```

than change the first condition

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || $_SESSION['submit1']) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
           if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
                unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit1']=false; //or unset($_SESSION['submit1']);
                //DO SOMETHINGS
           } else {
            header("location: ./index.php");
           }
       }    
       include_once('./my2page.php'); //**PAGE WITH SUBMIT2** 
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./my1page.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks...great! Where i must add `$_SESSION['submit1'] = (isset($_POST['submit1']))? true: false;` ?

Comment: I'm sorry i made a mistake add this lines and not the other one.

    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
        $_SESSION['submit1']=true;
    }

Add it just  before;

    if (isset($_POST['submit1']))

Comment: Can you correct the answer so that I can understand? Please

Comment: you still have the OP's redundant `if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token'])`  just thought I would mention it.

Comment: it's not a problème, he can send it again from the seconde formulaire and that wat he should do, else it will cause a probléme

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $_SESSION['submit1']=true;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || $_SESSION['submit1']) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
           if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
                unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit1']=false; //or unset($_SESSION['submit1']);
                //DO SOMETHINGS
           } else {
            header("location: ./index.php");
           }
       }    
       include_once('./my2page.php'); //**PAGE WITH SUBMIT2** 
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./my1page.php');
}
```

Comment: GOOD! it work but it give me some errors: on first page i see  Notice: Undefined index: submit1 on line 19 (exactly at `if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || $_SESSION['submit1']) {` and Notice: Undefined index: user_token on line 20 in my3page when i refresh (and after i need to delete cookie because i can't access anymore at my1page

Comment: Change all ` $_SESSION['submit1']` by  `code` $_SESSION['submited']  `code` and see if the warning steel the same or not

Comment: On my1page i see Notice: Undefined index: submit1 on line 19 (exactly at `if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || $_SESSION['submit1']) {` and Notice: Undefined index: user_token on line 20 in my3page when i refresh and everitime i need to delete cookies because i can't access anymore at my2page (and it don't redirect to index page)

Comment: Yes, the problem is in `$_SESSION['submit1']` as you say!

Comment: change this then to `if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit1']) && $_SESSION['submit1']))` mind the `||( ... ){`

Comment: ADD This line 

$_SESSION['submit1']= (isset($_SESSION['submit1'])) : $_SESSION['submit1'] : false;

OR

Change
(isset($_POST['submit1']) || $_SESSION['submit1'] by
( (isset($_POST['submit1']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit1']) && $_SESSION['submit1'] )

I recomand the seconde option

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I solved with that your code! But i don't understand why :D hahahaha

Comment: the condition is evaluated from left to right, in the case of an AND it will "giveup" on the whole condition if part of it is false,  So in the case the `$_SESSION` value is not set, it never checks if it is true.  In the case that it is it does, and the check get's rid of the undefined offset error.

Comment: by the way it "gives up" because all conditions must be true for AND, so once one is false, there is no reason to check the others, and because it is not checked when not set, you don't get the offset error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Your close you could possible just change this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'],$_POST['submit2'])) { //check isset on both
    if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
//         if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) { <--redundant check
           unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
           //DO SOMETHINGS
       }    
       include_once('./my2page.php'); //**PAGE WITH SUBMIT2** 
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./my1page.php');
}
```

Depending on if you want an `AND` or an `OR` the above is equivalent to this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) && isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
```

Obviously if you want an or then just put it here

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) || isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
```

It's not clear if you are talking about 2 POST's that are separate or concurrent

Comment: Now i have see that i can access to the page only with iexplorer,,, chrome return me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. probably is `if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token'])` as you say but how i can solve that without this? See first post please.

Comment: are you redirecting to the same page, which redirects to the same page again?  That will cause an infinite loop and the browser will give up.

Comment: please see now... i redirect to the same page only if token is expired... or at least I think...i'm wrong?

Comment: what page is all this code on, what do you mean `the same page`

Comment: So now i explain: my1page is a search form with submit1, my2page is a table populated from mysql db with submit2, my3page are 2 query (UPDATE) with results. I would like to avoid double insertions and so i'm using a token. I don't need to renew token in my2page becasuse it is only a SELECT query and so there aren't problem with double insertion (probably the cause of error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.) Furthermore I can show results in 2 ways: merge results (in my3page) with my2page (table) or have the results on a my3page (AS I CURRENTLY DO). (I would like to do all in one page without redirect)

Comment: i solved with replace `if(@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit'])` instead `if (isset($_POST['submit']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit']))`